# Issue with submit event listener

Tags: javascript, submit, addeventlistener

I am trying to make my first submit event listener so that the button responds to both a click event and an enter key event. Right now it is not responsive to either and I'm not sure why. I am not sending any information to another page - I just want it trigger other events.

```js
var domStrings = {
    submit: document.querySelector('#submit')
}
var checker = function() {
    var lcase;
    domStrings.submit.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('form submitted');
        lCase = guess.value.toLowerCase();
        turnCounter++;
        if (entryField.value.includes(lCase)) {
            for (i = 0; i < entryField.value.length; i++) {
                if (lCase === entryField.value[i]) {
                    retainAndReplace(domStrings.word.textContent, i, lCase)
                }
            }
        } else {
            //tell user they're wrong
            wrong.style.visibility = 'visible';
            wrong.classList.add('.fade-out-wrong')
            setTimeout(invisibleWrong, 4000);
            guessCounter--;
            if (guessCounter < 1) {
                //display game over
                over.style.display = 'inline'
                chances.textContent = `Guesses remaining: 0`;
                wrong.style.display = 'none';
                //hide dashes
                word.style.display = 'none'
            } else {
                chances.textContent = `Guesses remaining: ${guessCounter}`;
            }
        }
    })
}
checker()
```

```html
<input type = 'text' id = 'guess' placeholder = 'Letter Guess' maxlength = '1'>
<button type = 'submit' id ='submit'> Submit </button>
```

Comment: Are you sure this script runs after html load?
Please place the script at the end of the body.

Comment: when I change it to a 'click' event it runs successfully when clicking the submit button.

Comment: If a function is assigned to a variable and you call the function before it's assigned, then you are calling an undefined function. To prevent this you can do `function checker(){}` instead of `var checker = function(){}`, or you can just call the function after you define it instead of before.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I have changed the function call to below the function and am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) is fired on the `<form>` element itself — not on the button inside of it. So the solution is to wrap your elements in a `<form>`, to which you ought to attach the event listener.

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  output.innerHTML = guess.value
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="guess" placeholder="Letter Guess" maxlength="1">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div>Guessed letter: <span id="output"><span></div>
```